# How to change the imageview size dynamically in android for a particular image?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-relativelayout

Actually I am using Relative layout for image view. This image view is for receiving images from the internet to the application. The thing I need is can I change the image size dynamically for a particular images (say jpeg) and another size for attachments(docx,pdf), etc.

I used if condition for images and another if for attachments. Now how to set image size for receiving images and another image size for receiving attachments. I need to do dynamically. Note I am using only one image view for both images and attachments.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView>
id=iv
width=wrap content
height=wrap content
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>

for class file

if("image/png"){
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
or 
code to get images from web

}
else if(mimetype("application/pdf")
{
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc)
}

this is the model

Help me out!
```

Answer (score 4):

/*
                    requestLayout()
                        Call this when something has changed which has
                        invalidated the layout of this view.
                */

```
                imageView.requestLayout();
                imageView.getLayoutParams().height = height;
                imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
```

reference : https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-imageview-set-width-and-height.html

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams;
lp.width = x;
lp.height = y;
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp)
```

Comment: when I set the above code for images and attachments separately, all images and attachments take any one of the declared params. there is no variation for attachments size and images

Comment: Actually I am using Relative layout for image view. it means u use a RelativeLayout as a container?

Comment: xml file has relative layout which carries image view

Comment: <RelativeLayout>
<ImageView>
id=iv
width=wrap content
height=wrap content
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>

for class file

if("image/png"){
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
or 
code to get images from web
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams;
lp.width = 100;
lp.height = 100;
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp)
}
else if(mimetype("application/pdf")
{
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc)
}

this is the model

Help me out!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
ImageView ivImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
ivImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change image aspect ratio dynamically,

```
private void setPicDimensions() {
        Point screenDimensions = Utils.getScreenDimensions();
        width = screenDimensions.x;
        height = Utils.getHeightFromAspectRatio(width, 16, 9);// dynamically set aspect ratio value here its 16:9
    }

     // in your image view set layout params dynamically whereever you need to change
     //Declare height and width as int and iv_pic as imageview
     LayoutParams layoutParams = iv_offer_pic.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = height;
        layoutParams.width = width;
        iv_pic.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
       most important is:
  <imageview  android:scaleType="fitXY" />
   <RelativeLayout>
  <ImageView>
  id=iv
  android:scaleType="fitXY" 
  width=wrap content
  height=wrap content
  </ImageView>
  </RelativeLayout>

  for class file

   if("image/png"){
   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
   or 
   code to get images from web
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =     (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams;
   lp.width = 100;
    lp.height = 100;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp)
    }
    else if(mimetype("application/pdf")
    {RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =     (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams;
    lp.width = 50;
    lp.height = 50;
     imageView.setLayoutParams(lp)
     iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc)
    }

   this is the model

   Help me out!
```